# If $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{2^k}<\delta$, what can say about $\sum_{k=0}^na_k$? ($a_k\geq 0$, $k=0 , \ldots, n$)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Assume for every $0\leq k\leq n$, $a_k\geq 0$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{2^k}<\delta$. In my research, I need to find upper bound for $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$. Is there a bound less than $n2^n\delta$?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can get a trivial upper bound lower than $n2^n \delta$ as such:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a_k}{2^n}&\leq
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a_k}{2^k} \\
&< \delta
\end{align*}$$

Thus,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k < 2^n \delta$$

<strike>We can in fact go lower via the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), which tells us,</strike>

$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_iv_i\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i^2\right) $$

for any sequences $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and, $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$. In particular we have,

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k\right)^2 &\leq \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(2^{k}\right)^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{a_k}{2^k}\right)^2\right)\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}4^{k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a_k}{2^k}\right)^2\tag{*}\label{*}\\
&<\left(\frac{4^{n+1} - 1}{3}\right)\delta^2
\end{align*}
$$

Note that \eqref{*} employs the fact thats $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_i\right)^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i^2$ if every term $s_i$ is nonnegative.

We thus get a stronger upper bound for the series:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k <\left(\frac{4^{n+1}-1}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\delta$$

Edit: I realize this is not in fact a better bound and as shown by @MartinR, $2^n \delta$ is indeed the strongest possible bound.

Comment: The second part is now correct, but it is a *weaker* bound. $\left(\frac{4^{n+1}-1}{3}\right)^{1/2}$ is *larger* than $2^n$.

Comment: @MartinR apologies you are right! I should've checked my result more thoroughly. $2^n$ is indeed the best possible bound

Comment: Choose $a_0 = \cdots = a_{n-1} = 0$ and $a_n \ne 0$ to see that $2^n \delta$ is the best possible bound.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the correction! I have added strikethrough in my answer and an edit.